# render a table cell value with ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a prime faces table, where I can input a value in cell and I want to calculate another value in another cell of the same row. I find out the solution, where I render the all table, but my focus on the next row of the table ist lost.

```
<p:panel id="bestellPanel">
    <center>
    <p:dataGrid  var="artikelGruppen" value="#{bestellungUI.bestellungArtikelGruppenList}" rows="2" id="gridArtikelGruppen" >

        <p:column>
            <p:panel header="#{artikelGruppen.gruppeBestellungArtikelName}" style="text-align:center" >

                <p:dataTable var="selectedBestellungArtikel" value="#{artikelGruppen.listBestellungArtikel}" id="selectedBestellungArtikel" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">

                    <p:column >
                         <f:facet name="header"> Artikelname </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{selectedBestellungArtikel.artikelName}" />                      
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column >
                         <f:facet name="header"> Packungsart </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{selectedBestellungArtikel.packungsName}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column >
                         <f:facet name="header"> Anzahl Packungen </f:facet>

                         <h:inputText value="#{selectedBestellungArtikel.anzahlPackungen}" converter="javax.faces.Integer" style="color: #{selectedBestellungArtikel.message ? 'red' : 'blue'};text-align:right;"  converterMessage="Die Eingabe ist nicht eine valide ganze Zahl" id="anzahlPackungen">
                             <f:ajax execute="@this" render=":bestellungForm:bestellPanel" listener="#{bestellungUI.summierePackungen}" >
                                   <!--   <f:param  value="#{selectedBestellungArtikel}"/>-->

                            </f:ajax>
                        </h:inputText>
                    </p:column>
                     <p:column >
                          <f:facet name="header"> Bestellwert </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{selectedBestellungArtikel.bestellWert}" style="text-align:right;" id="bestellwert">
                            <f:convertNumber pattern="#,##0.00" maxFractionDigits="2" locale="de"/>
                         </h:outputText>
                    </p:column>


                </p:dataTable>

            </p:panel>                 

         </p:column>
         <p:column>

            <p:panel header="Summe #{artikelGruppen.gruppeBestellungArtikelName}" style="WIDTH: 100%; text-align:center"  >
                        <h:outputText value="#{artikelGruppen.summeBestellwert}" id="gruppeSummeBestellwert" >
                          <f:convertNumber pattern="#,##0.00" maxFractionDigits="2" locale="de"/>
                        </h:outputText>

            </p:panel>

         </p:column>

   </p:dataGrid >
```

My problem is the code snippet

```
 <f:ajax execute="@this" render=":bestellungForm:bestellPanel" listener="#{bestellungUI.summierePackungen}" >
```

The called function calculate a new value for id=bestellwert and a new sum with id=gruppeSummeBestellwert for the table .

This solution works, but I l've lost focus on the next row. How can I render only the editing row, or some wanted cells and the sum row, because I want to keep focus in the table.

Thank you in advance.